# R language - extract string between two delimiters

Tags: r

I want to extract the text between "Part Description:" and "- Installs" using R; similarly, need to extract other text - as the text is continuous not able to extract.

Sample text:

> Support Queue: WW_SC GD OB V5; V5 Business: ; Local 
>   Weekend: True; Local Holiday: False; *** NOTE: This is a 
>   PARTNER device. Please follow special partner process instead of
>   standard support chain. SupportID: 469
>   ********************************* ** Event and Event Attachments ** ********************************* Incident Number: 34c-48a6 OS Version: Windows Server,
>   2003 Event Time: 2015-07-10T00:29.7110Z Part Number:
>   xxxxxx-001, Part Description: 1000 watt AC hot-plug power supply -
>   Installs in the computer chassis as primary or redundant supply (800
>   watts at 100VAC to 1000 watts at 200VAC maximum power) - Requires
>   100-240VAC at 50/60Hz , RoHS Yes, CSR A Error Type: HW No attachments.
>   Recommended Action: The power supply in Bay 2 has failed and should be
>   replaced with spare part number xxxxxx-001.

Comment: something like `if(grepl("Part Description:", fixed=TRUE)) myStuff <- gsub(".*Part Description: (.*) - Installs.*", "\\1")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
sub(".*Part Description:(.*)Installs.*", "\\1", txt)
```

This substitutes the whole string by the part in between `Part Description:` and `Installs`. This results in: `" 1000 watt AC hot-plug power supply - "`

Or using `stringr` you can do:

```
require(stringr)
str_sub(str_extract(txt, "Part Description:.*Installs"), 18, -9)
```

Which gives you the same result.

Comment: The second function works perfectly, with first function I am not getting the exact result - along with the result, it gives the remaining text as well. This is tried with large amount of data not the sample that I mentioned above. Also, what does "\\1" mean? And, if there are many asterisks (*) just before "Installs" as mentioned in above sample, how to remove them using the first function